# create project laravel error packagist.org

Tags: laravel, composer-php, installation

when I create project using 
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project` 
something error like this 
`Content-Length mismatch
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date`. 
I've search what the problem, 
but most of the problem is when the `update composer` and must change the url package. but I want to make a new project. 
[image]
How I can fix it.

Comment: Can you run the command again with `-vvv` added and show the full output (and please paste it as text instead of posting an image)?

Answer (score 0):

First, run:

```
$ composer config --list --global        //this will get the composer home path.
[home] /root/.composer                   //it's my composer home path.
```

And then, edit the config.json in [home] directory, make it like this:

```
{
  "config": {
    "github-protocols": [
      "https,ssh"
    ]
  },
  "repositories": {
    "packagist": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.org"
    }
  }
}
```

It will make the packagist connection force https. And also you could config the composer.json in your project, this is a laravel sample would be look like:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  },
  "repositories": {
    "packagist": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.org"
    }
  }
}
```